# Python iterate over all possible combinations on boolean variables

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I have 6 booleas variables in a dict and I want to run my code on all all their possible iteration.
so I have:

```
params["is_A"] = True/False
params["is_B"] = True/False
...
```

and then for all possible combinations, I want to call

```
my_func(params)
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Do you want combination or permutations? if it's combination specify a combination of how many. edit: also show what you have tried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`itertools.product` can generate all the combinations:

```
import itertools

names = 'is_A is_B is_C is_D is_E is_F'.split()

def my_func(params):
    print(params)

for p in itertools.product([True,False],repeat=6):
    params = dict(zip(names,p))
    my_func(params)
```

Output:

```
{'is_A': True, 'is_B': True, 'is_C': True, 'is_D': True, 'is_E': True, 'is_F': True}
{'is_A': True, 'is_B': True, 'is_C': True, 'is_D': True, 'is_E': True, 'is_F': False}
...
{'is_A': False, 'is_B': False, 'is_C': False, 'is_D': False, 'is_E': False, 'is_F': True}
{'is_A': False, 'is_B': False, 'is_C': False, 'is_D': False, 'is_E': False, 'is_F': False}
```